# What to include when using Encode with PAR Packer

Tags: perl, dll, encoding, utf-16le, pp-perl-par-packager

I've been working with PAR::Packer to create standalone executable files out of Perl scripts. The only difficulty I have with it is figuring out what extra DLLs I have to force it to include via the `-l` option.

I'm now working with a Perl script that requires Encoding with utf16-le. The `Encode::find_encoding` function works just fine in the script, but it doesn't work after I have packaged it with `pp`.

Here's a tiny script (let's call it encode.pl) to illustrate the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
my $_UTF16 = Encode::find_encoding ('utf16-le');
print $_UTF16;
```

If you run this, it will print something like `Encode::Unicode=HASH(xxxxxx)`. Pack it up with `pp`, however, and it no longer works:

```
pp -o encode_test.exe encode_test.pl
```

Now when I run encode_test.exe, I get this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_UTF16 in print at script/encode_test.pl line 5.
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do (e.g. what libraries to include or any other solution) to make this work right even after packaging with `pp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `pp` with the `-x` option works, of course, but using it was unacceptable in my case because this runs the program, and since this is a GUI application this command would no longer be automatable.

The culprit was a run-time require used by Encode.pm, line 120, to load Encode::Unicode. To make this program work, I used the following:

```
pp -o encode_test.exe encode_test.pl -M C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Encode/Unicode.pm
```

Note that using backslashes (the Windows way) causes a failure in the `pp` command, so those had to be replaced with forward slashes.