# Perl .exe file: Can't call method “encode” on an undefined value

Tags: perl, exe, mojo

I am begginer of the Perl. 
I made my Perl script and I want to  make a Perl script into a self-contained executable. To create .exe file I used `PAR::Packer`. After creating and executing .exe file I get such error:

```
  Can't call method "encode" on an undefined value at Win32/Unicode/Util.pm line 36, <DATA> line 2125.
    Compilation failed in require at Win32/Unicode.pm line 14, <DATA> line 2125.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Win32/Unicode.pm line 14, <DATA> line 2125.
    Compilation failed in require at if.pm line 13, <DATA> line 2125.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at App/Weryfikacja/Term.pm line 7, <DATA> line 2125.
    Compilation failed in require at App/Weryfikacja/Log.pm line 8, <DATA> line 2125.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at App/Weryfikacja/Log.pm line 8, <DATA> line 2125.
    Compilation failed in require at App/Weryfikacja.pm line 17, <DATA> line 2125.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at App/Weryfikacja.pm line 17, <DATA> line 2125.
    Compilation failed in require at script/diagfull.pl line 54, <DATA> line 2125.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/diagfull.pl line 54, <DATA> line 2125.
```

I want to notice that Perl script runs well. What can cause my .exe file doesn't work? Maybe I need to add modules or something like that to .exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could provide the details how you used the pp utility from PAR::Packer, it might be easier for others to provide assistance.  Without those details, I'm going to assume that you did something like "pp -o test.exe test.pl".

The first thing that I would suggest would be to use the -c and/or -x options.  Those options are used "to determine additonal run-time dependencies".  Keep in mind that those are case-sensitive options.

If that doesn't fix all of the issues, you may need to use additional options.  Check the documentation for the [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) utility for more details on the other options.

Also, I noticed that you added the "mojo" tag to your question, so I'm assuming that your code is using Mojolicious.  If that's the case, you may want to check out this [blog](http://blag.nullteilerfrei.de/2013/05/17/building-perl-stand-alone-applications-with-a-gui-using-mojolicious-and-par-packer/) for some help on creating a stand alone application using Mojolicious.

Comment: As you wrote, I used "pp - o test.exe test.pl"

Comment: Thank you dasgar for your help. I used "pp -c test.pl" and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and for me the problem was solved by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523251/3227721 by [Nate Glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474819/nate-glenn) to this question [What to include when using Encode with PAR Packer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522945/what-to-include-when-using-encode-with-par-packer):

> The culprit was a run-time require used by Encode.pm, line 120, to load Encode::Unicode. To make this program work, I used the following:

> `pp -o encode_test.exe encode_test.pl -M C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Encode/Unicode.pm`

I used `-M Encode::Unicode`.